# ERROR: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again.NoClassDefFound error: DRPCExecutionException

Tags: java, apache-storm, noclassdeffounderror, drpc, bigdata

When I am trying to connect to storm-topology(v1.0.2) throuch DRPC client request I am getting the following error:

> ERROR: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again.
>       exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/apache/storm/generated/DRPCExecutionException

Answer (score 2):

First problem you have is that Apache Storm is missing from classpath. If you are using Maven, [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.storm/storm-core/1.0.2) are example coordinates to put in pom.xml - or alternatively you may need to dowload JAR-files from website and put them inside libraries directory. Then you might start to get more meaningful error message. Maybe you need to define JNDI resource?

Comment: Hi!! thank you for your quick reply. And yes we are using Maven and our storm topology is running perfectly without an issue. The issue comes up from drpcclient.execute() method that is supposed to connect storm-topology.

Answer (score 1):

This (JNI error) is very common error, it occurs when you change your jdk version. To solve this error you have to change the compiler setting only. Just right click on project and go to properties then go to java compiler and then select compiler compliance level to your JDK version....that's it, done!